# Finding the smallest topology containing a set of certain intervals

Tags: general-topology

For $\mathbf{R}$ we consider the family $S$ of subsets consisting of all the intervals of type $(m, M)$ with $m < M < 0$, all intervals of type $(m, M)$ with $0 < m < M$ ($m$ and $M$ real numbers) and the interval $[−1, 1)$. Denote by $T$ the smallest topology on $\mathbf{R}$ containing $S$.

I am trying to figure out what this topology would look like, but I cannot figure it out. I did figure out that not every subset of $S$ can be open in this topology, otherwise these subsets would generate the Euclidean topology (if I am correct). So I have been trying to come up with a basis to generate the smallest topology, but every time I end up generating the Euclidean topology, unless I use the basis $\{S, \mathbf{R}\}$. Is the topology generated by this basis the topology that I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

In general if $\mathcal S$ denotes a collection of subsets of a set $X$ then the collection: $$\mathcal T_{\mathcal S}=\{T\mid T\text{ is the intersection of a finite subcollection of }\mathcal S\}$$

will be contained in the topology on $X$ generated by $\mathcal S$, and moreover it will serve as a base of it.

In this context the intersection of finite $\varnothing\subseteq\mathcal S$  is the whole set $X$.

That means that the topology generated by $\mathcal S$ can be described by:$$\mathcal O_{\mathcal S}=\{O\mid O\text{ is the union of a subcollection of }\mathcal T_{\mathcal S}\}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: I’ll use $\mathscr{T}$ for the smallest topology generated by this family, and $\mathscr{E}$ for the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

- Show that $0\notin U\in\mathscr{E}$, then $U\in\mathscr{T}$.
- Show that if $-1,0\notin U\in\mathscr{T}$, then $U\in\mathscr{E}$.
- Show that if $0\in U\in\mathscr{T}$, then $[-1,1)\subseteq U$.
- Show that if $x>-1$, then $[-1,x)\in\mathscr{T}$.

Once you’ve done this, you’ll have all of the pieces that you need in order to write down a nice base for $\mathscr{T}$; one easy way to do it is to figure out what a nice local base at each point of $\Bbb R$ looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the smallest topology containing $\mathcal{S}$ is equivalent with finding the smallest topology containing $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S})$, i.e.: $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S}))$.

For any $\mathcal{S}$, one can associate a topology basis, a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the two axioms:

1. For each $x\in X$ there exists $B\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B$.
2. For each $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, there exists $B\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B \subset B_1\cap B_2$.

Now draw the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and two intervals $(m,M)$ and $[-1,1)$. You'll see the intersection is $[-1,M)$. We now have a basis 
$$ \mathcal{B}=\mathcal{S} \cup \{ [-1,M): M\in \mathbb{R}, -1<M<0\}$$